# Read FASTA into a dataframe and extract subsequences of FASTA file

Tags: r, subset, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a small *fasta* file of DNA sequences which looks like this:

```
>NM_000016 700 200 234
ACATATTGGAGGCCGAAACAATGAGGCGTGATCAACTCAGTATATCAC

>NM_000775 700 124 236
CTAACCTCTCCCAGTGTGGAACCTCTATCTCATGAGAAAGCTGGGATGAG

>NM_003820 700 111 222
ATTTCCTCCTGCTGCCCGGGAGGTAACACCCTGGACCCCTGGAGTCTGCA
```

Questions:

1) How can I read this fasta file into R as a dataframe where each row is a sequence record, the 1st column is the refseqID and the 2nd column is the sequence.

2) How to extract subsequence at (start, end) location?

```
NM_000016 1  3 #"ACA"
NM_000775 2  6 #"TAACC"
NM_003820 3  5 #"TTC"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Biostrings](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.13/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) package.

```
library("Biostrings")

s = readDNAStringSet("nm.fasta")
subseq(s, start=c(1, 2, 3), end=c(3, 6, 5))
```

Comment: This function is masking the repeats. How do we prevent that?

Comment: Can you give a little example? Maybe ask on https://support.bioconductor.org/ for specific use cases.

Comment: Oh, thank you :) I solved the problem using Python. Just treated them as strings. I wanted to delete those sequences which had repeats. So, I used string.isupper() to check that.

Comment: I kind of have the same question regarding the masking: `DNAString("TATCAAATACTCAAGCACtaaggaaacaggaaaatct")` will return `37-letter "DNAString" instance seq: TATCAAATACTCAAGCACTAAGGAAACAGGAAAATCT` 
Why is `aaggaaacaggaaaatct` not staying in lowercase?

Answer (score 19):

```
library("Biostrings")

fastaFile <- readDNAStringSet("my.fasta")
seq_name = names(fastaFile)
sequence = paste(fastaFile)
df <- data.frame(seq_name, sequence)
```

Comment: could you please explain your answer

Comment: @Prudhvi not OP but that looks like a function that returns a name vector. So the first step was to the name which is >xxx part of the fasta , 2nd step was get sequence and then last was to put that all into a dataframe.  Could had done it in one step though but this is much easier to read.  ```data.frame(name = names(fastaFile), seq =paste(fastaFile))```

Answer (score 5):

inspired by sgibb's answer above, I answer the first question as follow:

```
#read fasta file into R as a dataframe: 1st column as "RefSeqID", 2nd column as "seq"

library("Biostrings")
fasta2dataframe=function(fastaFile){
s = readDNAStringSet(fastaFile)
RefSeqID = names(s)
RefSeqID = sub(" .*", "", RefSeqID) 
#erase all characters after the first space: regular expression matches a space followed by any sequence of characters and sub replaces that with a string having zero  characters 

for (i in 1:length(s)){
seq[i]=toString(s[i])
}

RefSeqID_seq=data.frame(RefSeqID,seq)
return(RefSeqID_seq)
}
```

Example:

```
mydf = fasta2dataframe(myFastaFile.fasta)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `phylotools` to read your FASTA file into dataframe

```r
library(phylotools)
fasta.df = read.fasta("file.fasta")
```

for subseting the sequences, I like @sgibb answer.