# Merge rows if previous row contains a string that starts with a particular sign

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c(">A1", "aaaa", "bbb", "cccc",
            ">B2", "dddd", "eeeee","ff",
            ">C3", "ggggggg", "hhhhh", "iiiii", "jjjjj"))
```

This is what I want to get:

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c(">A1", "aaaabbbcccc",
            ">B2", "ddddeeeeeff",
            ">C3", "ggggggghhhhhiiiiijjjjj"))
```

As you can see, I want to merge every row between two rows that contain a string starting with ">" sign.
Frankly, I don't know where to start with this.
Please advise.

Comment: Are those `>A1` etc actually in your data frame as you shared it here?

Comment: BTW, it seems unnecessarily circuitous to use `as.data.frame(rbind(..))` here. `data.frame(V1=c(">A1","aaaa",...))` is a lot more straight forward (less obscure) to create a frame with a single column.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it @r2evans, I have edited the code to clear up my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cumsum(grepl(.))` for this.

```r
data.frame(
  V1 = unlist(
    by(df$V1, cumsum(grepl("^>", df$V1)),
       function(z) c(z[1], paste(z[-1], collapse = "")))
  )
)
#                        V1
# 11                    >A1
# 12            aaaabbbcccc
# 21                    >B2
# 22            ddddeeeeeff
# 31                    >C3
# 32 ggggggghhhhhiiiiijjjjj
```

Brief explanation:

- `grepl(.)` returns `TRUE` for each of the `>`-containing cells; then
- `cumsum` assigns that row and all rows until the next occurrence the same number:

  ```r
  grepl(">", df$V1)
  #  [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  cumsum(grepl(">", df$V1))
  #  [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
  ```
- `by(.)` does something to each of those groups; in this case, it returns a vector length 2, with the `>`-string first and all others concatenated.

Which is structured as your `df1`,

```r
df1
#                       V1
# 1                    >A1
# 2            aaaabbbcccc
# 3                    >B2
# 4            ddddeeeeeff
# 5                    >C3
# 6 ggggggghhhhhiiiiijjjjj
```

Comment: I'm with you @AllanCameron, it seemed to make more sense to produce two columns ...

Comment: Perhaps `grepl('^>', df$V1)` would be better than `grepl('>', df$V1)`? My guess is that this whole thing is an x-y problem, where the real issue is how to import text properly.

Comment: It does seem like an X/Y thing, sure. My guess is that either (a) the text file producer is either draconion, or setup to do something completely different; or (b) it was read in wrong or its real structure lost earlier in data processing. In either of those cases, it seems likely that the real data might require a different regex, in which case the `^` might be a red herring ... either way, added, it adds specificity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this was originally a fasta file, then use the dedicated package:

```
write(as.matrix(df), file = "tmp.fasta")

library("Biostrings")

readDNAStringSet("tmp.fasta")

# DNAStringSet object of length 3:
#     width seq                                                                 names               
# [1]    11 AAAABBBCCCC                                                         A1
# [2]     4 DDDD                                                                B2
# [3]    12 GGGGGGGHHHHH                                                        C3
# Warning message:
# In .Call2("fasta_index", filexp_list, nrec, skip, seek.first.rec,  :
#   reading FASTA file tmp.fasta: ignored 17 invalid one-letter sequence codes
```

Related post: [Read FASTA into a dataframe and extract subsequences of FASTA file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263636/read-fasta-into-a-dataframe-and-extract-subsequences-of-fasta-file)

Answer (score 1):

You could use string manipulation functions to insert separators at the start and end of each group, then collapse everything into a single string (including the inserted breaks), and then split the groups up using the separators.

Using base-R

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
    V1 = tail(strsplit(paste(sub("^(>.*)", "\n\\1\n", df$V1), collapse = ""), "\n")[[1]], -1),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Explanation: `sub()` matches values with ">" and inserts newlines before and after to separate each row group. `paste()` combines everything into one string. `strsplit()` breaks the string into separate values between the newlines and `tail()` removes the extraneous empty group at the start.

The same steps, but spelled out a bit more clearly using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df %>%
    # Insert separators before and after groups
    mutate(V1 = ifelse(grepl("^>", V1), paste0("\n", V1, "\n"), V1)) %>%
    # Combine all groups into a single string
    summarize(V1 = paste(V1, collapse = "")) %>%
    # Split into groups using the separators
    summarize(V1 = strsplit(V1, "\n")[[1]]) %>%
    # drop the empty group at the beginning
    filter(V1 != "")
```